# Can this fetch be done more "elegantly"?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I am using jOOQ and I am not quite sure if I am using it the way I am supposed to. I was wondering if my code below can be written more elegantly. By "*elegantly*" I mean that it is quite annoying to change basically *anything* regarding the columns. If I add, remove or change the order of the columns I'd have to change all result  and `Table<>` objects etc. I am quite sure that I'll encounter such requests like below a few more times in the future thus I'd like to know if I can simplify this.

In addition, I noticed that the result of `on.fetch()` and similar is a `Result<Record6<..>>`. I took a look at those `RecordX` classes. There are 22 of them. I don't think that I'll ever need that but what if I wanted to read 23 columns?

```
public List<StoreItemDTO> getItems(Long storeId) {

  // Get all item_ids for the store

  SelectConditionStep<Record1<Long>> where = this.ctx
    .select(STORE_ITEM.ID)
    .from(STORE_ITEM)
    .where(STORE_ITEM.STORE_ID.eq(storeId));

  // Get all store_item_details (all languages) according to the fetched item_ids

  Table<Record5<Long, Long, String, String, Long>> storeItemDetails = this.ctx
    .select(
        STORE_ITEM_DETAILS.ID,
        STORE_ITEM_DETAILS.STORE_ITEM_ID,
        STORE_ITEM_DETAILS.NAME,
        STORE_ITEM_DETAILS.DESCRIPTION,
        STORE_ITEM_DETAILS.STORE_LANGUAGE_ID
        )
    .from(STORE_ITEM_DETAILS)
    .where(STORE_ITEM_DETAILS.STORE_ITEM_ID.in(where))
    .asTable("storeItemDetails");

  // Join the result and get the items for the store in all languages

  SelectOnConditionStep<Record6<Long, Long, Long, String, String, Long>> on = this.ctx
    .select(
        STORE_ITEM.ID, 
        STORE_ITEM.STORE_ID,
        storeItemDetails.field(STORE_ITEM_DETAILS.ID),
        storeItemDetails.field(STORE_ITEM_DETAILS.NAME),
        storeItemDetails.field(STORE_ITEM_DETAILS.DESCRIPTION),
        storeItemDetails.field(STORE_ITEM_DETAILS.STORE_LANGUAGE_ID)          
        )
    .from(STORE_ITEM)
    .join(storeItemDetails)
    .on(storeItemDetails.field(STORE_ITEM_DETAILS.STORE_ITEM_ID).eq(STORE_ITEM.ID));

  Result<Record6<Long, Long, Long, String, String, Long>> fetch = on.fetch();

  // ..

  return null;
}
```

Comment: What about `fetchMaps()` Then you can access via column name? [http://www.jooq.org/doc/2.5/manual/sql-execution/fetching/](http://www.jooq.org/doc/2.5/manual/sql-execution/fetching/)

Comment: @Valijon This could be an alternative for `fetch()` I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need the type safety, don't use it. E.g. the following works just fine, too

```
// Get all item_ids for the store
SelectConditionStep<?> where = this.ctx...

// Get all store_item_details (all languages) according to the fetched item_ids
Table<?> storeItemDetails = this.ctx...

// Join the result and get the items for the store in all languages
SelectOnConditionStep<Record6<Long, Long, Long, String, String, Long>> on = this.ctx...
```

The extended type safety is very nice for the compiler when it can perform type inference, e.g. when you're writing:

- `UNION`s
- `IN` predicates
- When you fetch your results into lambda expressions
- etc.

You're probably writing all these types down because you're using IDE auto-completion, and your IDE makes the most specific suggestion first. But using wildcards will work just as well, in the above case like this e.g.:

```
Result<?> fetch = this.ctx 
                     // .. 
                     .fetch();

for(Record record : fetch) {            
    String value = record.getValue(STORE_ITEM_DETAILS.NAME);            
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

> I don't think that I'll ever need that but what if I wanted to read 23 columns?

Nothing significant changes. See also the manual:
http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/record-n

You can still choose whether to use explicit record typing (no degree on the record):

```
Result<Record> result = query.fetch();
```

... or whether you use a wildcard:

```
Result<?> result = query.fetch();
```

Comment: I allowed myself to make an edit. I didn't know that I can get the fields from `Record` using `getValue(Field<T> field)` :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: @StefanFalk: Oh, really? So you always dereferenced them by index, e.g. `record.value3()`? Oh my :) Yeah, this usage makes things a lot easier... :)

Comment: :D No, to be honest I didn't came to the "fetch data from the server" part yet. ^^ My project made a halt over the winter semester and I spent a lot of time designing my abstraction layers and learn Spring Security etc. :)

Comment: I don't want to start a new question.. Would you be so kind and help me here out again? I am trying to group my results into something like this `Map<Long, Result<Record>> intoGroups2 = fetch.intoGroups(STORE_ITEM.ID);` but I just don't know how that would work. ^^

Comment: The compiler doesn't like it. "*Type mismatch: cannot convert from Map<Long,Result<capture#8-of ?>> to Map<Long,Result<Record>>*" I am not sure which version of `intoGroups()` would be the right one here.

Comment: Ah, I missed that detail. Yes, that will be when using a wildcard will be a bit more hairy. The only type that captures that result is: `Map<Long, ?>` (not useful) or `Map<Long, ? extends Result<?>>` (also not really nice). In order to work around that, you'd need your own `<R extends Record>` type. Perhaps, at this point, a new question would be the right way to go? We still haven't run out of "new question tokens" ;)

Comment: Ah okay, I see! I will state a question as soon as I am back from work :) Thanks Lukas. I have to say your commitment is impressive :)

Comment: @StefanFalk: Someone has to do it :) Would you be interested in a quick 10min chat? I'd love to learn more about your application / jOOQ use-cases. I'm sure there's a lot to learn from your experience, to make jOOQ even better.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't mind but I am not sure if my input would be that beneficial for you since I am 1) Rather new to jOOQ and 2) also rather new to SQL :D First I used Hibernate just to avoid SQL until I red a lot of horror stories about it :D If you want we can make an appointment but I think I can be much more useful around the end of February where I should have a lot more code that actually uses jOOQ :) (the reason why this takes so long is because it's the end of the semester and I am also working 20h/week :P)

Comment: @StefanFalk: New is good. I'd like to learn about the "struggle" in the beginning. It'll help improve the biggest pain points for new users. But with that much work per week on your side, we do indeed better postpone this :) I'll reach out later, then.

Comment: I'd suggest to do that around the middle/end of February. I'm sure we'll here from us. :)

Comment: @displayname: You seemed to have gone "undercover"? :) How are things going with jOOQ?

Comment: Hey! :) Yes, I decided to remove my name since a guy at the university accused me on Twitter that I would let math.stackexchange do my math homework. It had political reasons and although I totally disagree with his opinion I decided to remove my name for now :D Things with jOOQ are good. I'm still happy to use it although I still have not written a lot of lines in jOOQ. The reason is that atm I am alone with my project and therefore I'm taking quite slow steps :D

Comment: Yesterday I discovered that if I want to use a Record that I created e.g. from a DTO, I would have to call `ctx.attach(myRecord)` in order to be able to `myRecord.update()` it. I am not sure if I am doing it right but it's quite convenient to update a record in just a few lines - assuming you have a DtoToRecord mapper.. For the future I am curious how I will tackle caching. At the moment I am not caching anything but the time might come where this changes XD

Comment: Ah, the stack exchange homework police... :-/ Too bad about having written only few lines of jOOQ code ;) Hmm, not sure if something is wrong with your attaching. Usually, you don't have to attach things. Perhaps, ask a new question? ;) Caching is out of scope for jOOQ, usually you cache on a higher abstraction level. But that too is worth a separate question :)

Comment: I am going to ask about the attachment :) Regarding the caching I am already aware that I'll have to do this by myself :D I hope I will be able to do so :D